# Why am I getting RichEdit line insertion error when I call Delete in OnChange event?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, richedit

I've googled and checked many places for a solution, but all cases I found differed or involved something more advanced than simply adding or deleting lines. Basically, I want to make a sort of scrolling rich edit (alternative would be moving the caret to the bottom, which I already found a solution for).

I'm adding lines to it and checking `Lines.Count` with the `OnChange` event of the rich edit and as soon as it reaches value greater 15 I want to call `Lines.Delete(0)`, however I get the error:

```
RichEdit line insertion error
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: The error you are getting is the `RichEdit line insertion error`, what you might mention in your question. I'll try to see why, but you can simply delete the line before you insert the new one.

Comment: When you type the words "the error", the **very next thing** you should be typing is the **exact** error you're getting, with the complete error message.

Comment: @KenWhite, as TLama said, that already is the exact error, unless this provides you with more info: `First chance exception at $7505b9bc. Exception class EOutOfResources with message 'RichEdit line insertion error'.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the `RichEdit line insertion error` because of check added to the Delphi 2009 version. This check verifies if the insertion of a new line has been successful and this check uses for it the selection position. Unfortunately, for the following piece of code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RichEdit1.Clear;
  RichEdit1.Lines.Add('1');
end;

procedure TForm1.RichEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if RichEdit1.Lines.Count > 0 then
    RichEdit1.Lines.Delete(0);
end;
```

The workflow looks like this:

> ***1. - TRichEdit.Lines.Add → TRichEdit.Lines.Insert***
>
> Get the position of the first char for the line where the string will be inserted, add the linebreak to that string, setup the selection (0 length, starting at the line beginning) and insert the string by performing EM_REPLACESEL message, what except the text insertion, changes also the selection position. The check mentioned above has not been performed yet, and in the meantime that text insertion causes the OnChange event to fire, where the TRichEdit.Lines.Delete is called.
>
> ***2. - TRichEdit.Lines.Delete***
>
> Delete does something similar. It gets the first character index of the deleted line, setup the selection, now in the whole line length and performs the EM_REPLACESEL message with the empty string. But it also changes the selection position of course. And that's the problem, because we are now going back to the last line of the TRichEdit.Lines.Insert function.
>
> ***3. - TRichEdit.Lines.Add → TRichEdit.Lines.Insert***
>
> Now the last thing of a previous call of the TRichEdit.Lines.Insert function remains to be done, the evil check based just on the selection position. And since the position has been changed by the meantime deletion, it doesn't match to the expected result and you are getting the error message.

Also, before someone fix this issue, don't use even this, it will cause the same error:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RichEdit1.Lines.Add('1');
end;

procedure TForm1.RichEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RichEdit1.SelStart := 0;
end;
```

If you didn't fell asleep from this boring story, then I can suggest you just to avoid the manipulation with the lines in OnChange event as much as you can (better to say, only when you know what can happen).

Comment: Forgot to mention, it was written by the code from Delphi 2009. I don't have another version by hand at this time, so I can't check if it's the same in the other versions as well.

Comment: I think you can assume that it's the same for (nearly) all versions, I have Delphi XE2. Aight, it seems that it works if I trigger the deletion not in the OnChange but just right after adding a new line in the same procedure, I suppose that's the best way to handle this for now?

Comment: Keeping the insert and delete lines together on one place (without using OnChange event) is fine and more general from my point of view. That error message is just annoying and should IMHO be removed from there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of what is actually happening behind the scenes with RichEdit. Also, wont it 'bug out' without that error and just add weird behavior? Or you mean to fix as in make it work as originally attempted by me? (Had to delete the last comment cause you already addressed the SelStart within an event.)

Comment: I would say the check with that exception brought more harm than favour. I can't imagine what can happen that the line wouldn't be inserted; maybe not enough capacity ? Still, the only thing you would get due to this real failure is the exception raised, but that's all. Comparing to consequences of the selection change (or lines modification) in events like `OnChange` or `OnSelectionChange` it's quite a high price. To your question, it's as you said; you would have to recalculate the selection position considering a deleted line, not only restore the position before line deletion.

Comment: I am just doing Append() and still getting this error in XE8. Is there a workaround?