# Delphi disable mouse buttons and enable again

Tags: delphi, click, mouse

I need to disable both mouse buttons on the event OnMouseEnter of a TRichEdit component and enable again on the event OnMouseLeave.

Setting the TRichEdit enabled = false does not solve my problem.

Any tips ?

Comment: Well, disabling the rich edit won't disable mouse buttons. Or is that perhaps not the real problem.

Comment: May I ask why? This seems highly counter to the way Windows applications work. What is the objective (goal) of doing this? There may be a better way.

Comment: I don't understand why people are voting to close as "unclear what you're asking" it's very clear to me what's being asked, what's not clear is why.

Comment: I have a form splitted in half. On the first half is a pannel created at runtime with user defined fields of different DataTypes. The other half is the TrichEdit that contains the text created using the fileds that the user filled on the pannel. The procedure that updates the richedit is activated on the fields onExit Event. If a field is focused and the user clicks directally on the TRichedit, raises an exception on the lineupdate event. The tip from Sertac Akyuz worked beautifully.  Thanx to all !!

Comment: If you are getting an exception then you are probably doing something wrong in the first place, and then trying to solve the symptom rather than the cause.  Please show your actual code and explain your goal, there is probably a better design to accomplish it.

Comment: Leo, aren't you getting *"RichEdit line insertion error"* error and manipulating with lines in the `OnChange` event, e.g. ? If so, then [`be careful`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10475566/960757).

Comment: The exception only occurs if I click imediatelly after exiting one of the fields that were created at runtime. Some of those fields are TDBRichEdits and I need to insert paragraphs on the resulting TRichEdit to separate each piece of information. On each insert, i need to get the paragraph position on the resulting TrichEdit. That´s Why I get the error if I point the mouse anywhere inside the Trcihedit after exiting one of the fields. As I mentioned before, the text is updated on the TRichEdit uppon the OnExit Event of those fields.  Thanx to all for each contribution. Problem Solved !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass your rich edit so that to intercept mouse button down/up messages. Then you don't need to watch for the mouse entering, leaving the control. Example:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  private
    FSaveRichEditProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure RichEditWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
    ..
  end;

  ...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSaveRichEditProc := RichEdit1.WindowProc;
  RichEdit1.WindowProc := RichEditWindowProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.RichEditWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK,
    WM_MBUTTONDOWN, WM_MBUTTONUP, WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK,
    WM_RBUTTONDOWN, WM_RBUTTONUP, WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK:
      begin
        Message.Result := 0;
        Exit;
      end;
  end;
  FSaveRichEditProc(Message);
end;
```

Comment: Better use [`EN_MSGFILTER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787974(v=vs.85).aspx) notification (like [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/PhN01PGP) e.g.).

Comment: @TLama - Still you need to subclass and it seems more work, why is it better?

Comment: That's right, however that notification is better because it's exactly for the purpose of *"event eating"* for this control.

Comment: @TLama - Thanks for reminding double clicks. I don't agree that it's better because its purpose is that, while I can do the same with less work. This is about that *semantics* again I guess.

Comment: @TLama - When is it better, I can see. When you're handling notifications on the parent - as the api is really intended to be used - then you don't need to additionally subclass the control. However VCL makes it easier/promotes handling messages on the control itself, which then both methods end up with subclassing. AAMOF you're not using `WM_NOTIFY` like you've linked, but `CN_NOTIFY`.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz : 
You should point out how the user gets into the RichEdit1 field now. Usually there are more than one component on TForm.

Comment: @Sertac, I think I see your point; you mean that the notification should be consumed by the control's parent. Well yes, it should be, but according to the VCL design of the other common controls, it's better fitting here. moskito-x, that's what OP should think about when designing against UX.

Comment: @moskito - Why would I know that? Maybe it's the first control on the form. Maybe he'll use tabs. This is what happens when what is asked is done.